# using event load with .on() on a text field is not working

Tags: jquery

im trying to trigger a load event (for example set default value) on my textfield using this:

```
    $("#textfield1").on("load" , function(){
       $("#textfield1").val("WEEE");
    });
```

which won't work.

If i do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     $("#textfield1").val("WEEE");
  });
```

or this:

```
 $("body").on("load" , function(){
    $("#textfield1").val("WEEE");
 });
```

then i get the desired effect. am i using the `load` wrongly in the first snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

via [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

So, basically yes: the textfield will never fire the `load` event.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements don't have a `load` event.

Only elements with a `load` event are `body`, `img` and possibly `link` and `script`